# Replace a bean by a mock in Helidon test

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, cdi, helidon

I have a Helidon application and I would like to test (part of) it.

My test is annotated with `@HelidonTest`, and now I would like to replace one bean by a mock (and configure this mock, use all other beans as they are found, but with the mock injected).

I did figured out how to:

- Replace one bean by a test implementation (separate class): By annotating the test implementation class with `@Priority(1)` and `@Alternative` and supply it by annotating the test with `@AddBean(MyBeanTestImpl.class)`.

  - But I can not create a mock (with Mockito) as an individual class.
- Produce a `mock(MyBean.class)`: By creating a producer method and annotate it with `@Produces`:

  - But it clashes with the real bean and gives: "WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type..."
  - When I annotate it also with `@Alternative` it is simply ignored.
  - I can not annotate it with `@Priority(1)`, because this annotation can only be applied to types and parameters.

Any idea how I can replace one bean by a mock?

Comment: You may want to look at the section in the CDI specification on specialization: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#specialization  Then you may want to look at specialization as it relates to producer methods: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#specialize_producer_method I am not any kind of an expert on Helidon's testing annotations, but in general they seem to simply take code you'd write (`addBean`) and turn it into annotations for some reason. You might be able to get rid of that too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It's one step further but still not exactly working for my case. When I annotate the producer with `@Specializes`, it throws "WELD-000078: Specialized producer method does not override another producer method", because my bean is a class and now it's a method...

Comment: I think perhaps you should read about specialization in CDI again, as Helidon doesn't get involved at all with alternatives and specialization. My guess is that, just as the error message says, whatever class it is that hosts your producer method does not extend another bean class.  You might consider adding the `cdi` tag to this question, since that is really the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried setter injection to manually inject mock beans.

**Class under test**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeService {
    private ExternalService externalService;

    @Inject
    public void setExternalService(ExternalService externalService) {
        this.externalService = externalService;
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        return externalService.getData();
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@HelidonTest
class SomeServiceTest {
    @Inject
    private SomeService someService;

    private ExternalService externalService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        externalService = Mockito.mock(ExternalService.class);
        someService.setExternalService(externalService);
    }

    @Test
    void doSomething() {
        Mockito.when(externalService.getData())
                .thenReturn("Mock data");
        String actual = someService.doSomething();
        Assertions.assertEquals("Mock data", actual);
    }
}
```

There are also methods to mock a whole bean by mocking the constructor as well. For that, we have to make use of @Observes annotation

```
@HelidonTest
public abstract class HelidonTestHelper {


    private MockedConstruction<ExternalService> mockedConstruction;

    void init(@Priority(1) @Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) ContainerInitialized containerInitialized) {
        mockedConstruction = Mockito.mockConstruction(ExternalService.class);
        //mock common beans here. This will be executed once application scope is loaded.
    }
    void onStop(@Priority(1) @Observes @Destroyed(ApplicationScoped.class) ContainerShutdown containerShutdown) {
        //do cleanup here if needed.
        mockedConstruction.closeOnDemand();
    }
}
```

Once the above is done, instead of helidon test, you can extend the helper class we created.

```
    class SomeServiceTest extends HelidonTestHelper {
        @Inject
        private SomeService someService;
    
        @Inject //this will be a mock 
        private ExternalService externalService;
        
        @Test
        void doSomething() {
            Mockito.when(externalService.getData())
                    .thenReturn("Mock data");
            String actual = someService.doSomething();
            Assertions.assertEquals("Mock data", actual);
        }

      }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second version (with `MockedConstruction`) works as I wished. However, I've also had to add the dependency for mocking static methods (constructor): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-inline

Comment: The second methods has some pitfalls I would like to share (however, I still like it!). First, make sure your mocked bean does not get initialized somewhere else (transitively) by **another initializer with higher priority** (e.g. `init(@Priority(0) @Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class)...`-method). Second, your bean must be initialized (first used) in the **same thread** your test runs (if unsure, set a breakpoint in your beans constructor and, if it still gets constructed, check the thread).